# How to bind data to model which is retrieved from Oracle Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle

I'm new to mvc.Before i used to code with entity framewok and it's easy.But i have to do some different things.I have looked some tutorials but i couldn't understand very well and they don't cover my needs.
I connected my Visual studio and got data from oracle 12c successfully using by Oracle Data Provider for .net,not by using entity framework.Code is at above.

```
string constr = "Data Source=localhost/orcl;User Id=HOSPITAL;Password=HOSPITAL;";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();
OracleCommand cmd;
OracleDataAdapter da;
conn.ConnectionString = constr;
OracleCommandBuilder cb;
DataSet ds;    
conn.Open();

string sql = "Select * from BABY
IDENTITY.FIRSTNAME,IDENTITY.LASTNAME,IDENTITY.MOTHERNAME,IDENTITY.FATHERNAME,
IDENTITY.BIRTHDAY,IDENTITY.GENDER,BABY.WEIGHT,BABY.HEIGHT FROM BABY 
INNER JOIN IDENTITY ON BABY.FILE_NO=IDENTITY.FILE_NO";

cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
cb = new OracleCommandBuilder(da);
ds = new DataSet();

da.Fill(ds);

conn.Close();
```

I want to bind this data to my model and display at view.My model is as the following class.

```
public class Baby
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public string FatherName { get; set; }
    public string MotherName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }

 }
```

How can we bind dataset to my model or how can i bind my query result directly to my model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity framework can be used with oracle:
http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm

you could use an adapter that set's all the model properties from the datatable eg:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt = ds.Tables[0];
IList<Baby> Babies = new List<Baby>();
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
var baby= new Baby();
baby.FirstName = dr["Baby firstname column name from db"].ToString();
baby.Weight= (int)dr["Baby weight column name from db"];

Babies.Add(baby);
}
```

Or use Automapper to do this for you if you don't want to hand code a lot of left right code.
[Using AutoMapper with DataTable with missing columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434750/using-automapper-with-datatable-with-missing-columns)
http://automapper.org/

Comment: I can't use entity framework because it needs primary key at the tables but they don't have and i am not allowed to change table design.

Comment: oh, ok.  U can use the second approach then.